# Running two queries with Datamapper in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datamapper

I want do perform two queries, one to get the count of all results and one to get the actual results 9 by 9. My problem is when I try to get the count of the results: The second query gets all the 9 rows from database without the `WHERE` clause.

```
$courses = $this->load->model("course")->where("deleted",0);
$courses->where("country",strtolower($country));
$courses->count(); // returns 15
$courses->offset(($per_page)*9)->limit(9);
$courses->get(); // returns 9 rows from all database (like select * from courses limit 9) without where country=france
```

My problem is I want to count all the results but I want to get just 9 results for pagination purposes

***Help needed for newbie codeigniter user***

```
class Course extends DataMapper {

    var $table = 'course';

    var $error_prefix = '<li>';

    var $error_suffix = '</li>';

    function __construct($id = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you must perform two queries agaisnt the database:

- One for counting.
- One for retrieving the results you want.

Your problem is you think the active records is keeping your results. When you perform a `count`, Datamapper will return you the results of the query and will be ready for a new query, so, it's not keeping the where clause.

Try doing it in two steps. For counting:

```
$courses = $this->load->model("course")->where("deleted",0);
$courses->where("country",strtolower($country));
$counting = $courses->count(); // returns 15
```

For retrieving results:

```
$courses = $this->load->model("course")->where("deleted",0);
$courses->where("country",strtolower($country));
$courses->offset(($per_page)*9)->limit(9);
$results = $courses->get(); // returns 9 rows from all database (like select * from courses limit 9) without where country=france
```